# Carousel with many Image size in Ant Dessign

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I'm new to ReactJs and currently learning how to use Ant Design. I've tried to use the Carousel component and faced some problems. When I tried to insert some images into the Carousel, the images are not fit the size of the Carousel Component. Each image has different sizes and I want it all to fit the carousel size. One example here (original size:1024x1024): (the second image just got 50% of the width of the Carousel size)
[image]

[image]

```
<Row gutter={[16,8]}>
                <Col md={14}>
                    <div>
                    <Title level={1}>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</Title>
                    <Paragraph> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
                    Fusce ut neque neque. Fusce rutrum pretium mauris et dictum. 
                    Donec ac lacus vel orci rutrum commodo a vel orci. 
                    In aliquet dolor in arcu interdum convallis. 
                    Duis eleifend nibh eros, nec interdum ipsum commodo ut. 
                    Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam consequat nibh ac diam cursus fermentum. 
                    Sed et nisi nibh. In dolor metus, venenatis sit amet quam sed, iaculis pharetra orci. 
                    Etiam non lacus ac risus pharetra fringilla eu sit amet velit.
                    Pellentesque iaculis arcu eu nisl maximus dapibus.</Paragraph>
                    </div>
                </Col>
                <Col md={10}>
                    <div>
                    <Carousel style={carouselStyle}>
                        <div>
                        <Image src="https://xuongmaydosi.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/Fabric-la-ten-goi-tieng-anh-de-chi-mot-tam-vai.jpg" style={{width:'100%'}}></Image>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                        <Image src="https://mooneepondssewing.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/homespun-fabrics-melbourne.jpg" fluid></Image>
                        </div>
                    </Carousel>
                    </div>
                </Col>
</Row>
```

and the CSS I tried but not work

```
const contentStyle = {
    height:'400px',
    Width:'100px',
    objectFit:'fill',
  };
const carouselStyle ={
    borderRadius:'20px',overflow:'hidden',
    height:'400px',
    background:'teal',
}
```

The App.js file:

```
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import HomeIntroduction from './components/HomeIntroduction.js';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <HomeIntroduction></HomeIntroduction>
    </>

  );
}
```

Whay should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<Image src="another-img" fluid />
```

Comment: It seems not to be worked

Comment: when you use fluid then don't use height and weight of your style code.
remove height and weight from your code and use fluid

Comment: I removed the style and did like above but nothing change

Comment: I will update the Image of Image 2 above

Comment: ok can you show me your project. then i can solve it

Comment: I've just updated it above, it's just that, ... I tried many ways but it does not work.